# I want to merge two sequelize query into single sequelize query

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

What I'm trying to find is first select those comments which contain my search param it will return postId's then select the whole post with all comments including that comment also which we've searched using search param!

```
app.get('/search_', (req, res, next) => {
    var search = req.query.search;

comment.findAll({
        attributes: ['PostId'],
        where: {
            the_comments: {
                [Op.like]: `%${search}%`
            }
        }
    })
    .then(data => {
        var array = [ ];
        for (var x in data) {
            console.log(data[x].PostId);
            array.push(data[x].PostId);
        }
        console.log(array);
        Post.findAll({
                include: [
                    {
                        model: comment
                    }
                ],
                where: {
                    id: {
                        [Op. in]: [array]
                    }
                }
            })
            .then(result => {
                res.json(result);
         })
    })

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Post.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: comment
    }],
    where : {
        id : {
            [Op.in] : [connection.literal(`select PostId from comment where the_comments like '%${search}%'`)]
        }
    }
})
.then(result => {
    console.log('result',result);
    res.json(result);
}).catch(error=>{
    console.log(error);
    res.json(error);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
Post.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: comment,
            required: true,
            where: {
                    the_comments: {
                                    [Op.like]: `%${search}%`
                                  }
                   }
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: No, this will return only those those comments where the_comments like `%${search}%` , but what we want is to get all comments if any of the_comments like `%${search}%` thats why above green ticked answer holds true, by the way thanks for replying .